# Spark Structured streaming - Handling Deduplication

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

As per the doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication, we can handle duplicates using combination of withWatermark and dropDuplicates().

**Question:**

1. using withWatermark() when we have possibility of historic data corrections:  what if there is a possibility of incorrect data from source occasionally and we would need to consider the updated data published by source to queue at later stage. for ex: consumers get to know that source has published incorrect data after 4 months, in that case if have defined withWatermark with few hours or days, we would miss the restated data by source. What is the best practice to handle such cases?
2. Continuation of above, for the usecases where log data is written to queue (TBs per day) and streaming job writes to storage. In such cases involving large volume of data, is using withWatermark() always recommended to handle dedup? If we do not use withWatermark() for dedup, would not 'state' data grow too large (considering it has to maintain all state from beginning) to fit into memory over a period of time? What is the recommendation for such cases?